# Angular ngchange doesn't fire for <pre contenteditable="true">

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a  tag to fire the ng-change event but to no avail. The purpose is to watch changes to post.content. The code is pretty straightforward and parts of it are omitted for brevity, but it's basically a ng-template that is repeated like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts" data-id="[[post.id]]" data-rank="[[post.sortrank]]" class="post">
    <ng-include src="post.template"></ng-include>
</li>
```

The repeated template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="postText.html">
    <pre ng-blur="savePost($event, post)" ng-change="changePost()" ng-model="post.content" class="postText" contenteditable="true">[[post.content]]</pre>
</script>
```

The JS:

```
$scope.savePost = function($event, post) { //This fires correctly
    console.log($event);
    console.log(post);
};

$scope.changePost = function() { //This doesn't fire at all
    console.log("changed!");
};
```

Can this be because of the contenteditable attribute? Because I can get the ngChange examples working on the Angular tutorial site.

Comment: contentEditable tags don't fire a change event...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [akatov's angular-contenteditable.js](https://github.com/akatov/angular-contenteditable).

From the docs... JS:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['contenteditable'])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.model="<i>interesting</i> stuff"
  }])
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <span contenteditable="true"
        ng-model="model"
        strip-br="true"
        select-non-editable="true">
  </span>
</div>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/meTFzFLdzO9hoVPG22cM?p=preview)